# Searching records by first letters of any word in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Searching records by first letters of any word in string.
I need to search records by multiple probes from single row in sql
e.g.

**Table:**

```
AcCode      AcTitle  

1       Hussain Mills Limited  
2       Nishat Chunian Limited  
3       Nishat Mills Limited  
4       MCB Bank Limited  
5       Allied Bank Limited
```

**Required**
When searched by string "Ni Lim" should return record 2 and 3
When searched by string "Bank Li" should return record 4 and 5

Comment: Please share what you tried so far and not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think you can do this with `replace()` and `like`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where acTitle like '% ' + replace(@string, ' ', '% ') + '%'
```